# Is it possible to get results for one way trips using Sabre's Destination Finder?

Tags: sabre

### I am working on a flights planning app and considering using Sabre to handle my backend.

My app requires an "Explore Destionations" functionallity, something simillar to `Google Flights' Explore Destionations` featrue.

In theory, `Destination Finder` would have been perfect for the job.
The problem is, `Destination Finder` doesn't seem to provide a way to search for **one way** trips. In other words, you have to provide a *return date*.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achive this, Either by using `Destination Finder` or using a different API?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Destination Finder will only provide Round Trip Lead Fares as part of the Inspirational Shop request.

For One Way Shopping, you can look at the Bargain Finder Max API under Search for Air, available in both REST and SOAP.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max

Best

Comment: Thanks @jmacagno. With BFM, Is it possible to achieve Destination Finder type search where you don't need to specify the destination so the that the response returns with all available destinations?

Comment: Not at the moment, only destination finder supports Inspirational Shopping.

Comment: @jmacagno Multistop destination travel search for flight which one is best in sebre?

Comment: Would recommend looking at Bargain Finder Max. https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Bargain Finder Max APi

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max

Set

```
OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.TravelPreferences.TPA_Extensions.TripType.Value="OneWay"
```

I tired with DXB=>LHR but it returned connecting airports but for LAX=>JFK direct results I guess sabre is not strong in europe may be thats the reason